# Reverse for 'beriNilai' with arguments '('SI 43 01',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['grader/beriNilai/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']

Tags: python, django, sqlite

> UPDATE, i found what making this error, but i havent found the solutions, the cause of this error was `SI 43 01` is a string, after i changed that to a simple integer like `1,2,3` , i dont got any error.

im trying to print a data from table called `t_pengguna` where the `kelas` field is equal to the data that is being clicked by the user, so im trying to make something like `select nama from t_pengguna where kelas = .....`, i tried to pass the clicked data using parameter, but i got this reverse error, here is my `urls.py` file:

```
url(r'^beriNilai/(?P<pk>\d+)$', tambahNilai, name='beriNilai')
```

and here is my `views.py` file:

```
def tambahNilai(request, pk):return render(request, 'grader/beriNilai.html', {'siswa' : t_pengguna.objects.filter(kelas=pk)})
```

and here is my `html` file, where i make the button to pass the parameter:

```
<td> <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'beriNilai' matkuls.kelas %}">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> beri nilai
                  </a> </td>
```

anyhelp will be appriciated, thanks before, stay healty!

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py do this...

```
url('beriNilai/<[YOUR_ARG_TYPE]:pk>', tambahNilai, name='beriNilai')
```

eg

```
url('beriNilai/<int:pk>', tambahNilai, name='beriNilai')
```

Tell me if problem still persists...

Comment: sorry, caret should be removed now, UPDATED

Comment: `kelas` in english is like `class` or `classroom` that you have in school or highschool, i wrote it using text, so it should be string, but i still got the same error

Comment: have u changed like this `<str:pk>`

Comment: can u tell me the data type of `keras` by checking one more time..

Comment: the data type of `kelas` is string